# In moderator elections, selection option should be visually more clear

Tags: feature-request, design, election

I was just voting in community moderator elections over on Physics SE and looking through what I chose so far, and I think the layout is not very clear:

[image: screenshot from community moderator elections]

A green bar around a blue button; my eyes are good, and I can see it, but it's not very easy to spot when quickly scrolling through the page. Can we have a visually better representation of the selected choice?

Comment: It took me a while to work out what you were complaining about. I hadn't realised that you'd actually selected an option, which means +1.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Why didn't I think of it? :-)

Comment: I don't disagree that the colors should be changed, but there is a clear representation in that the flair of the candidates you've voted for also shows up on the right side of the page.